# Simple Java TCP socket protocols

Tags: java, sockets, serialization, tcp, protocols

I'm trying to find a reliable way to send control messages that obey a defined protocol in order to tell the server what kind of data he will receive. For example, I want to send a pure text message to invoke a remote method:

```
#METHOD1#CLOSE#
```

or I want to send a serialized object to the server:

```
#OBJECT# .......here comes the serialized object data....#CLOSE#
```

So basically I just want to send string control messages that are completely independent 
of the stream content that follows.

By wrapping an input stream into a Scanner object I'm able to extract strings from the input stream, but if this stream is a serialized object then the object can't be restored afterwards. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why don't you just use one of the many existing protocols for this purpose? For instance, JSON-RPC? Do you have any specific requirements?

Comment: If possible, it should be a pure socket based solution. I just would like to know how this could be done.

Comment: "if possible" is no valid reason. Which is why I asked for your requirements. There is no reason at all to hack your own protocol if an existing one already fits your need. Do not reinvent the wheel!

Comment: It's an assignment. Protocols for strings are not a problem, because I can easily append a control message to the actual message string. However, the easierst solution seems to be to subclass ObjectOutputStream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a scheme like Base64 (e.g. use a library from Apache) to encode the Object from bytes into a string and then back.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
new ObjectOutputStream(baos).writeObject(object);
String serializedObject = Base64.encode(baos.toByteArray());

byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(serializedObject);
ByteArrayInputStream baos = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
Object object = new ObjectInputStream(baos).readObject()
```

Comment: What about Java's BASE64Encoder/Decoder? So, basically I have to encode the object to a string and then append that object string to the control message string, right? To decode the message I read the chars that represent the control message and, if the message says it's an object, I go on adn decode the rest of the string to an object.

Comment: Yes, that's right. You can use any Base64 encoder/decoder you like.